# Convert Java HashSet to PHP

Tags: java, php

```
1  for (int i=0; i<paymentList.size(); i++) {
2     listClassDate.addAll(
3         getClassDateList(paymentList.get(i).getClassIdx())
3     );
5  }
6
7  HashSet tmpClassDate = new HashSet(listClassDate);
8  listClassDate = new ArrayList<>(tmpClassDate);
9
10  Collections.sort(listClassDate);
11
12  for (String classDate : listClassDate) {                            
13     contentsList.addAll(getSeriesClassBook(
14         selectedSeries.getSeriesCode(), 
15         classDate, 
16         paymentList
17       )
18    );
19  }
```

I'm converting a project from Java to PHP, but since I know little about Java, quite hard to convert it. My problem on the code above are the following:

1. In line 7, what the `HashSet` does to listClassDate? How can i make this in PHP?
2. In line 12, `for (String classDate ...`. I haven't tried "strings in PHP for loop" because i'm assuming `classDate` is always array in PHP.
3. The classDate is only my problem in the parameter, because that is a Java thing.

Parameters for `getSeriesClassBook()` method:
`getSeriesClassBook(String seriesCode, String classDate, List paymentList)`

Comment: In php all about  collection is array , where you can handle key and value, So you need to take out each element and put in php array

Comment: Your 3rd problem is not a question. Please can you rephrase?

Comment: @Michael and luk2302, my apologies. I think Michael has corrected it.:)

Answer (score 0):

1) It's a quick way to remove duplicates from the list. They makes a set by copying the list, which automatically removes duplicates. They then put it back into a list again.

2) It just a foreach loop. [The same concept exists in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

I don't understand question 3.

Comment: Since the php foreach loop returns key/value "Array", the 2nd parameter of `getSeriesClassBook()` which is the classDate which required "String" now doesn't meet the required type of argument. This make me confuse.

Comment: It removes the duplicate duplicate value?